# SQLite poor performance issue in multi-user local-network environment

Tags: c#, performance, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

We use SQLite as shared DB in our application. (I know this is not the best solution but server/client architecture was not possible)
There are only a few users, a very small db and just few writes.

The application is written in c# and we use [System.Data.SQLite.dll](http://system.data.sqlite.org/) but the problem occures also for example with the [SQLiteDatabaseBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

As long as only one user connects to the DB and queries some results, it is very fast. Just some milliseconds. One user can establish multiple connections and execute select statements in parallel. This has also no impact on the performance.

But as soon as another user from a different mashine connects to the db, the performance becomes very poor for every connected user. The performance keeps poor as long as all connections/apps are closed. 
After that, the first user connecting, gets the good performance back until the next user connects.

I tried many things:

- PRAGMA synchronous = OFF
- updated to the lates sqlite version (and created a new db file with that version)
- DB-File read-only
- network share read-only for everyone
- connection string with different options (nearly all)
- different sqlite programms (our application and SQLiteDatabaseBrowser)
- different filesystems hostet on (NTFS and FAT32)

After that, I wrote a little app that opens a connection, queries some results and displays the passed time. This all in an endless loop.

Here is the Code of this simple app:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder conBuilder = new SQLiteConnectionStringBuilder();
        conBuilder.DataSource = args[0];
        conBuilder.Pooling = false;                                    
        conBuilder.ReadOnly = true;

        string connectionString = conBuilder.ConnectionString;

        while (true)
        {
            RunQueryInNewConnection(connectionString);
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
    }

    static void RunQuery(SQLiteConnection con)
    {
        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "select * from TabKatalog where ReferenzName like '%0%'";
            Console.WriteLine("Execute Query: " + cmd.CommandText);

            Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
            watch.Start();

            int lines = 0;
            SQLiteDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
                lines++;

            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Query result: " + lines + " in " + watch.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms");
        }
    }


    static void RunQueryInNewConnection(string pConnectionString)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(pConnectionString, true))
        {
            con.Open();
            RunQuery(con);
        }

        System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.ClearAllPools();
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();           
    }
```

While testing with this little app, I realised, that it is enough to let another system take a file handle on the sqlite db to decrease the performance. So it seems, that this has nothing to do wih the connection to the db. The performance keeps low until ALL file handles are released. I tracked it with procexp.exe. In addition, only the remote systems encounter the performance issue. On the db file host itself, the queries runs fast every time.

Has anybody encountered the same issue or has some hints?

Answer (score 1):

Windows does not cache files that are concurrently accessed on another computer.

If you need high concurrency, consider [using a client/server database](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html).

Comment: Thx for the try but I don't need high concurrency. I just want to read from the sqlite db from multiple clients in parrallel in an appropriate time.

Comment: What you are saying is that with SQLite on Windows, concurrency is not high enough.

Comment: This is the question :-). I cannot belive, that this is a common issue with sqlite and Windows or smb Shares. The execution times of simple queries increases from 100ms up to 30k ms. Now I would like to verify those informations with experiences from other users with those settings before we replace the db.

Comment: I have similary problem, but it seems that it really depends on the server (i still searching what), on some computer 1 server 32 clients, there aren't any performance problem, on another server with only one client it is very slow.